# Can not upload application using Xcode 8.3.1

Tags: xcode, app-store, submission

I am trying to upload my application using Xcode 8.3.1

While validating the process getting an error
[image]

How can I resolve the issue.

**Note : I have added the account in the preference.**

**Edit :**

Please see the details,
[image]

Comment: if you added the account in the preference, do you still see the "Add Account..." button?

Comment: I have added the account and I can see the account. I have updated the question.

Comment: And you are still seeing the first dialog, the "No Accounts with iTunes Access" one, when trying to access your archives?

Comment: @VineeshTP did you manage to get it work? I'm facing the exactly same issue.